# "not ... anywhere" vs "nowhere"

Tags: no-not

with "*not ... anywhere*":

> **(1a)**: *I've ordered some food for us. Can I ask you **not to go anywhere** until a courier has brought it*?
>
> **(2a)**: *Okay. I am **not going anywhere***.

As far as I'm aware, (1a) and (2a) are both correct.

---

with "*nowhere*":

> **(1b)**: *I've ordered some food for us. Can I ask you **to go nowhere** until a courier has brought it*?
>
> **(2b)**: *Okay. I am **going nowhere***.

As far as I'm aware, (2b) is correct, whereas (1b) is not.

---

By what rule can we replace "*not ... anywhere*" with "*nowhere*" [as in (2a) and (2b)] and by what rule not [as in (1a) and (1b)]?
Thanks!

Comment: I think (1b) is OK.

Comment: I agree that (1b) is okay.